# grunt-contrib-requirejs compile gives an error while r.js works manually

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I am having problems with running requirejs as a grunt task to compile my js-files. When I run it manually (r.js.cmd -o configfile.js) with the same config file everything seems to work.

It seems that the grunt task is ingoring path definitions and is not capable to find my lib files.

```
>> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
>> '/path/to/project/js/lib.js'
>> In module tree:
>>     module
>>       libs/another-lib
```

The path should be /path/to/project/js/lib/lib.js. My main js-file (the one in data-main-attribute) has a requirejs.config call with correct path mapping ('lib': 'lib/lib.js'). After that I use them as parameters in a require call which starts the application.

My requirejs task configuration:

```
requirejs: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            name: "bootstrap",
            baseUrl: "submodule/js",
            mainConfigFile: "submodule/build.js",
            out: "submodule/js/bootstrap-built.js"
        }
    }
}
```

The only difference between `grunt requrejs` call and `r.js.cmd -o build.js` should be the grunt task configuration. They are using the same configuration file after all. What am I doing wrong or is there some kind of issue with paths in grunt-contrib-requirejs?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My problem was a conflict between requirejs task options and the mainConfigFile. I wanted to use the same config file from the submodule in the main project but there is a different base url configured (submodule/js/ -> js/).

I haven't found a way to override options from the config file so I had to copy them to the task configuration. It isn't pretty but at least it works now.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more about the "conflict"? I'm facing the same problem and my configuration looks OK (similar to your's and to those of other, similiar SO questions with the same error)

Comment: The conflict was between baseUrl-attributes in the main requirejs task configuration and the submodule configuration file. I couldn't use the submodule configuration and I had to copy the configuration from the "submodule/build.js" file to the requirejs task configuration.